# How to target block 1, 3, 5 etc. in a loop with PHP counter

Tags: php, loops, counter

I'm trying to add a div class "row" to my 1st, 3rd, 5th block etc.

I have the basics down, but it keeps targeting blocks 2,4,6 etc. I've been bashing my head for an hour because I assume it's really simple, but knowing little to none PHP i'm just not getting it right.

This is what I have:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"row\">ROW";
}
?>  

    <p>Title #<?php print "$counter"; ?></p>

<?php 
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
    echo "</div>";
    }
?>              

<?php $counter ++; ?>
```

Anyone who can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's targeting rows even numbers it's because you're doing

```
$counter % 2 == 0
```

You need to understand what the `%` does. The `%` is a [Modulus Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp), which will get the remainder of $x divided by $y as stated in the link.

So if you want to get the odd numbers, you'll have to do

```
$counter % 2 != 0
```

Or

```
$counter % 2 == 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time finding what the code actually did because I dont know the terminology. I'll make sure to remember this!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$counter % 2 == 1` to target odd numbers